# bash if -f in home directory

Tags: bash

I try to determinate, if a given path points to a file or a directory. I tried this with following code:

```
#if $mypath is a file
if [[ -f $mypath ]]; then
```

and

```
#if mypath is a directory
if [[ -d $mypath ]]; then
```

Both of these snippets are working fine, when the given path is absolute e.g. /home/user/mydir/... But when the given path starts with a ~, like ~/mydir/... both of these snippets will return true, regardless if the path points to a file, or directory.

Does anybody know, what I'm missing, or if it's even possible?

Comment: Unrelated: The variable called `PATH` is _very special_. It contains a list of directories where commands may be used.  Please use another variable name, preferably lower case.  See e.g. [Are there naming conventions for variables in shell scripts?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/42847)

Comment: I can't reproduce this in `bash` 5.0.  How do you assign the value to your variable?

Comment: In fact, if `$mypath` contains an _actual_ tilde character, which has not been expanded to a home directory, both should test should _fail_ (unless there's a file or directory with an actual tilde in its name at that path).

Comment: I fetch them from a config file, which is filtered, by a few simple grep commands.
`conf=$(cat /path/to/conf | grep -v "#"
    | grep -ve "^$")`

Comment: What do you mean with both tests should fail? That both won't work correctly, or just return a false?
And what do you mean with an actual tilde character? Would they automatically be expanded in some cases?

Comment: Sorry. By "fail" I mean "return false".  The tilde is expanded only when it occurs unquoted (at the beginning of a word, or just after `=` or `:`). It would not be expanded in e.g. `p='~'; [[ -d $p ]] && echo ok` and `ok` would not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem was, that I was fetching the path from an config file, and thus the path was saved as string. Trough this, **the tilde was not expanded**, which is the cause for the problem.
My workaround was just to manually replace the tilde with $HOME, which will be expanded, even if the path is quoted. So basically:

```
mypath="${mypath/#\~/$HOME}"
#if $mypath is a file
if [[ -f $mypath ]]; then
```